# Frameworks available to .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, frameworks, enterprise

I would like to build an application that will run on a web, this is for an enterprise solution, but I don't know what kind of framework that I'll be using, does anyone out there could recommend a framework that is best suited in .NET/ASP.NET application that could handle DAL, BLL and GUI, other than CSLA.NET?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "framework"? UI Libraries, ORM-Tools or something else? Thanks.

Comment: There are THOUSANDS of such frameworks out there catering to ASP.NET applications, much like it is in Java. Do you have any specific need? Dependency Injection? Unit Testing? ORM? UI? etc?

Comment: Better to describe what _features_ you are seeking to implement in this enterprise-level web application. Perhaps then can better suggestions and recommendations be provided.

Comment: Better edit your question than commenting about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for something like a .NET equivalent of JBoss, then no, there isn't one product that provides a do-all framework in the .NET world.

However, there are lots of products, mostly on the .NET 3.5 stack itself that can be pieced together to provide a solid framework.

- Windows Communication Foundation (networking);
- Windows Workflow Foundation (work flow);
- Enterprise Library Application Blocks (Caching, Logging etc.);

Object Relatation Mapper

- Entity Frameworks;
- NHibernate;
- [LLBLGen](http://llblgen.com/)

[Inversion of control / dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

- [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity)
- [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)
- [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html)
- [Ninject](http://ninject.org/)
- [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm)

Comment: MEF is not an IoC container, it is an extensibility framework. The Castle project is more then IoC, Castle Windsor is their container.

Comment: @Matt: Edit as fit please. I see you have the 750 reps required.

Answer (score 1):

@biozinc's suggestions all look good, I would just add the [inversion of control/dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) options too, like:

- [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity)
- [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/)
- [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually [.netTiers](http://www.nettiers.com/) generates besides the dal some bll and some user controls/web pages. So I think it is the closest to what you are searching.

I personally use [subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/), because:

- it uses ActiveRecord pattern which I like (it's simple and easy)
- is lightweight
- creates scavenger pages out of the box... (so some UI :) )

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative ioc container is [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another good OR mapper is [LLBLGen](http://llblgen.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would add [Managed Extensibility Frameworks (MEF)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef) to any Enterprise .NET project I was starting.